# Api / services for receiving sms (text messaging) online

Tags: api, sms, gsm, sms-gateway

My current project requires us to receive text messages online. It's hard to wade through the search results as many of the are just websites with about 10 numbers for everyone to use.

I am looking for services along the lines of what is being offered at http://www.tropo.com

You can send and receive text messages online on your own private generated phone number within the US or Canada.

Preferably free, just need a few more before I make any decisions

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Disclaimer, I do developer evangelism part time at Nexmo.*

Here are a few paid SMS APIs:

- [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com)
- [Twilio](http://twilio.com)
- [Tropo](http://tropo.com)

You *may* be able to hack something together that works for free, but you risk that solution being disabled by whatever provider you use (for example, some people send SMS via Google Voice, but I wouldn't recommend relying on that).

Since you're receiving SMS, Nexmo would be a good solution when it comes to price. You only pay for the virtual number (roughly $1 a month), and all incoming messages are free.

Comment: According to https://www.vonage.com/communications-apis/sms/pricing/, receiving a message costs $0.0065 per message.

Answer (score 0):

Try [www.twilio.com](http://www.twilio.com) they have a good API and it is free while testing.